# Get translations in AEM use javascript API

Tags: javascript, adobe, aem

I would like to get i18n translations on server side javascript use API and then pass to template. I cannot get translations on client side as granite client library is enabled only on author mode. I'm trying to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
use(function () {
    return {
        i18n: JSON.stringify({
            currency: granite.I18n.get('some.translation.key'),
        })
    };

});
```

Is there any option to do this?

Comment: And why not the standard HTL or JavaScript way?

Comment: @ronnyfm I cannot use client site Granite object to get translations as it is loaded only editor mode and finally I just passed it in HTL way (I mean {'translation.key' @i18n} but there are a lot of translations and all of them are passed to javascript component so I wanted to group it using use-htl js API and I'm wondering if it is possible